# Refresh a dynamic iframe while checkbox is checked every 2 min

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I cant seem to understand what I am doing wrong with this I am trying to add in a check box that will target the Iframe created by my predecessor but being a novice to JavaScript I have thus far used snippets of code from various sources to come up with this Frankenstein. I have started courses on java but I'm long off making these codes myself for now.

```
<b>STATUS TAG</b>

<a href="[removed]" target="custFrame" class="acenButton">▲</a>

<a href="[removed]" target="custFrame" class="decButton">▼</a>

    <!--Space-->&nbsp;||&nbsp;
    <!--Refresh page Box-->
<b>Auto Refresh 2Min</b>

    <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="1" autocomplete="off">
    <script>
        if (iframeElement.contentWindow.location.hash == "custFrame") {
            $("[name=toggle]").prop("checked", true);
            pageRefresh = setTimeout(function() {
                iframeElement.contentWindow.location.reload();
            }, 120000);
        }

        $("[name=toggle]").click(function() {
            if (!$('[name=toggle]').prop('checked')) {
                (iframeElement.contentWindow.location.hash = ""
                clearTimeout(pageRefresh);
            } else {
                (iframeElement.contentWindow.location.hash= "custFrame";
                pageRefresh = setTimeout(function() {
                    iframeElement.contentWindow.location.reload()
                }, 5000);
            }
        })
    </script>
    <!--Space-->&nbsp;||</p>
<iframe id="custFrame" name="custFrame" src="google.com" marginheight="0" onload="javascript:autoResize(this);" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="80%"></iframe>
<script>
     var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({    onReady:  
        function() {        socket.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)   
        }
    });
</script>
```

Inner URLs changed to google for testing

I should mention that I have various Quickbase API commands with the buttons on the top so it must target the frame and cannot revert back to the default url.

Answer (score 0):

This code is completely working for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this will run when the document is fully loaded
function init() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
   input.onchange=check
    function check(){
     var start=setTimeout('reload()',3000)
     StartStop=input.checked ? start : clearInterval(start)}
 }

// this reloads the iframe, and triggers the next reload interval
function reload() {
 var iframe = document.getElementById('reloader');
 if (!iframe) return false;
 iframe.src = iframe.src;

}
// load the init() function when the page is fully loaded
window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="checkbox" id="JustChecked" >checked to get latest<br>
<iframe id="reloader" width="200" height="100" src="test1_frame.html"/>
```

Comment: I think you may have missed a few spaces, i tried using this but it didnt seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/rpratt009/e4t22tze/4/